# To call servlet from javascript function, called on onClick event without redicting page to link in 'href'

Tags: javascript, html

I have an  tag with href and onClick event. I want to execute the function specified for onClick event and then redirect the page to the link in href. But when i call servlet from that function,the page get redirected to the link in href rather than that servlet.I want to first complete the processing in servlet and then redirect that page to href lin.What can be done?

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" onclick="createHttpRequest(this); return true; ">Google</a>
```

This is the javascript function used to call servlet.

```
function createHttpRequest(obj)
{
    link=obj.href;
    if(typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();     
    } 
    else if(window.ActiveXObject)   {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");

        if(!request) {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }


    if(request) {

        url="http://localhost:8080/HitCounter/InsertCount?sent_url="+link;

        request.onreadystatechange = handleRequest;
        request.open("GET",url,true);
        request.send(null);

        }
    else {
        alert("error on Page createHttpRequest");
    }   
    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return true;
```

should be

```
return false;
```

Within the `onclick` attribute and the method - return false prevents the default action - ie to follow the link.